# Website hangs only on certain clients ; if ViewState is disabled, loads at normal speed

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

This is very weird and it has taken lots of time to reach this point.

I have certain clients (from any computer on their network) and on one of my remote-working colleague that when loading some of our sites, the page hangs for 3-4 minutes before displaying.

The same page, on the same client machine, when connected to a wireless network loads fine.

We have checked DNS problems and the DNS resolution works fine.

Inspecting the page load in Firebug, I can see that the ASP.NET page goes into receiving state fairly quickly but then it takes forever to receive.

The head of the HTML file loads, in fact the Firebug's Net tab shows loading CSS, JS files, however the ASP.NET page itself takes, as said 3-4 minutes.

If, while it is loading, I right click and select View Source I see the full HTML content loaded in 1-2 seconds (in Firefox, View Source re-fetches the page from the server)

If while loading in IE, I right click and select View Source (in IE the View source corresponds to what the browser has got available at the moment) I can see that the HTML content is loaded up to halfway through the ViewState, if I keep re-asking for View Source, I can see slightly more of the ViewState loaded.

As a test I have therefore disabled ViewState all together and the page load as fast as it does in our office.

I know that ViewState is and ugly beast, it takes a big chunk of bandwidth and always takes a toll on page load time, however this is not the point.

I do not understand why that affects only certain machine connected to certain networks.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

EDIT:

Re-trying loading the page with ViewState disabled, and now the page load hangs again, further down the HTML content when I view the source in IE.

Interesting is:

When the same page is loaded in HTTS, it loads fine!

FURTHER ADDITION:
The site in question is http://www.theclifftownhouse.com/

Comment: I suspect its more of a speed and bandwidth issue. Like when you are receiving your data chunks, viewstate occupies the majority of it so for low bandwidth network, client is not able to receive the full data.

Comment: Can you try measuring the download speed of a large static file? If that's still slow, you have a network issue rather than a ViewState/ASP.NET issue.

Comment: @GiuseppeR - I assume the clients and the colleague both are using wireless network that works?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes when they do use wireless network that work fine, please see my addition to the question, when the same site is loaded with HTTPS it loads fine

Comment: If HTTPS works fine, and HTTP suffers, might there be some over-zealous anti-virus, firewall, or proxy server getting involved on your client's network?

Comment: @NeilMoss Their IT guy confirms there is not, however even if it was something at the ISP level which we cannot control, (UK, BT provider) any other site they load work fine, even heavy content sites.

Comment: @GiuseppeR - This sounds like something specific your website is using.  So what configuration differences are there between the wired network and the wireless network?  Are they actually two seperate networks or are they connected to one another.  I don't  see how we can assist you if we don't know what your website even does.

Comment: @Ramhound - They are two separate networks, it was tested to exclude something related to machine setup.

Comment: @NeilMoss Their internet connection has low bandwidth <0.8-1Mbps. I have tried a 3.2MB image and it took 23s, ~1Mbps. The ASP.NET HTML file size if 13.1KB, when loaded from their machine, it loads the first 4.9KB and then hangs and load the remaining 8.2KB very slowly.

Comment: @Ramhound the website is: http://www.theclifftownhouse.com/

Comment: @GiuseppeR - Which connection is slow?  The wire connection or wireless connection?  This really sounds like a configuration problem on the network side.  There must be a difference in the two configurations if one works and one doesn't on the exact same machine.

Comment: @Ramhound - Their wired connection does not work, but only for this site. Unfortunately we cannot get back to the client and blame their connection because they can browse any other site absolutely fine.

Comment: @GiuseppeR - "Any" is a strong word.  Its either something you are doing that most sites don't both doing or its a configuration problem unique to the wired connection.  I am going to guess its a configuration problem.

Comment: OK - no new ideas, but for diagnostic purposes, can you run netmon on the client's machine and play spot-the-difference between the request and response on the two networks?